# How to import react native github repo to a working app

Tags: react-native, github

Currently having issues on applying the repo of https://github.com/prscX/react-native-photo-editor to a working app on my phone using expo.

I dont have any basic on react native and i would really appreciate if someone can give me the instruction on making my app have the following module.

Answer (score 0):

react-native-photo-editor is native lib still not support with the expo.

You can start app development without expo.

**Setup React Native**

```
install react-native
react-native init TestNative
cd ./TestNative && react-native run-ios
```

Then follow these [steps](https://github.com/PascalSun/PhotoEditor-SDK-React-Native-Demo)

https://github.com/PascalSun/PhotoEditor-SDK-React-Native-Demo